# Cannot create new module in magento2 - php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, mysql

I followed exactly this setup:
https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-minimal
and added the `registration.php` file, and run `php bin/magento module:enable Company_Basic`, but after I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get the following error:

```
[PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

If I change from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in `env.php` I get:

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Now the website throws this error:

```
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Company_Basic
```

I'm using mamp. I installed magento2 ok, but now it appears that mysql is connecting. Any ideas? Thanks!

Update: If I run `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --version`
I get

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld  Ver 5.6.25 for osx10.6 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that php and mamp mysql did not communicate. I was using mac php and mac mysql. But my database is in mamp mysql.

Inserting this in my bash profile:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH
```

made sure that in command line I'm using mamp php and mamp mysql.