# Error when running bin/magento setup:upgrade after creating Module on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, bin-magento

I'm trying to create a module on a local installation of Magento 2.1.4.

i'm getting this error when running bin/magento setup:upgrade:

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

[PDOException]                                    
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]
```

After this i tried this solution: [Cannot create new module in magento2 - php bin/magento setup:upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91086/cannot-create-new-module-in-magento2-php-bin-magento-setupupgrade)

The outcome was the same and there is not much explanation on what this did to solve the problem.

I also read solutions from almost a year ago when apparently this was a common issue deleting var/cache, var/generation and var/di but that didn't worked either.

Comment: Check the health of your mysql server. Try restart it and see what happens.

Comment: Check your database connection string !! something is wrong or missing there !! also one more thing check your mysql server is it working or not ? issue is related to mysql and database configuration related

Comment: I know mysql server is working, i'm trying to check the path for mysql connection, one of the solutions i've been reading about talks about changing it in the bash profile

Comment: It could just be that the username for the DB in the app/etc/env.php is not correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple,  try the following commands. I have encountered this error, and I have overcome.

```
rm -rf var/di/* 
rm -rf pub/static/_cache/* 
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
rm -rf var/generation/* 
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```

In magento 2

> `var/di` has been replaced by `generated/metadata`
>
> `var/generation` has been replaced by `generated/code`

I switched to Developer Mode, and deleted the below files.

```
rm -rf generated/metadata/* 
rm -rf pub/static/_cache/* 
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
rm -rf generated/code/* 
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```

never delete `pub/static/.htaccess`.
putting star `*`at the end does not delete `.htaccess` file in the folder.

you may also need to run setup di compile to optimize and regenerate magento2 file system.

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact same error when i was working on a site that was remotely hosted but i had the mounted on my machine using sshfs. When i tried to do this locally i got your error. When i logged into the remote serve through ssh i was able to run `setup:upgrade` just fine. So this points to issues with your connection to MySQL.

As your set up is most likely different then what i'm doing, i think the issue is running a local server that is using a different version of pph or MySQL then what is running in your terminal.

Take a look here and see if this clears up the issue for you:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html